# How to create a dynamic URL in SPRING MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a requirement to open a PDF when the user clicks on a particular employee id present in a table. Like:

```
Employee id url
123         View
234         View
```

When user clicks on the View corresponding to that row, details of Employee id should open in a pdf. 
Someone please give me pointers on how to move forward on this. I am using JAVA Spring MVC framework.
Also need to know how will I create VIEW hyperlink, as this comes in a coulmn of a table. I am populating this table from Java Class.

My Controller Class:

```
@RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView getHeaders(PortletRequest portlestRequest, PortletResponse portletResponse){


        TableDAO dao = new TableDAO();
        List<String> headersList = dao.getHeaders();

        TableView tableView  = new TableView();
        tableView.setGetHeaderCount(headersList.size());
        //System.out.println("tableView::");
        tableView.setTableHeaders(headersList);

        List prepaidBillingDetailsList = new ArrayList();

        prepaidBillingDetailsList = dao.getPrepaidBillingInfo();

        tableView.setPrepaidBillingDetailsList(prepaidBillingDetailsList);

        return new ModelAndView("tableView", "tableView", tableView);
    }
```

My JSP:

```
<table border="1px" bordercolor="black" width=80% align="center">
 <tr>

    <c:forEach var = "headerList" items = "${tableView.tableHeaders}">
        <th>
            ${headerList}
        </th>
    </c:forEach>

 </tr>

<c:forEach var = "headerList" items = "${tableView.prepaidBillingDetailsList}">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var = "headerList" items = "${headerList.stringlst}">
                <td>
                    ${headerList}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="<c:url value="editEmployee.htm">  
                        <c:param name="msisdn" value="${tableView.msisdn}"/>  
                    </c:url> ">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

In this, First headerList will get my eadrs of the table, Next header list will display the data for of my employee class. Now in the last coulmn i need inks, which will take me to the PDF of that particular employee.

Comment: Can you post some portion of your jsp page ?

Comment: Did you read any of the documentation at all? This is all very clearly explained.

Comment: @chrylis: Could you please suggest which documents you are suggesting?

Comment: Use pathVariables or requestParams to carry employeeId to one of your controller method and there do the stuffs to open relevant details in PDF.

Comment: I am not able to create URL itslef. I need to set the URL in the object which i am returning to the JSP like My employeeBean has 2 attributes: EmpId, url. Now what should i set in the URL attribute so that when i am returning the object EmployeeBean, then it should come in my table and then when user clicks on VIEW then pdf should get opened. Please suggest how to create this URL

Answer (score 0):

You can form your view link url something like www.appdomain.com/App/Profile?id=123

view

and then map your controller with this url and get the id parameter from url and with the id get the details of the user and display it.

Second way is you can also get the url like www.appdomain.com/App/Profile/123

view

i.e. id as a path variable and get this path variable in the controller and get the details and display.

Comment: How to create URL (VIEW). and set it in the Object which i am returning to the my jsp?